# Prompt user for saving PDF reports generated using pdfsharp

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I'm currently working in a project in wpf with c#. I have a problem with report generation using pdfsharp. Report is successfully generated but i need to prompt the user to manually select the path where they need to store(save) the report generated. So i just used SaveFileDialog but failed. Please help me with this...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code for Save.

```
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";
        // Create an empty page
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
        // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        // Create a font
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);
        // Draw the text
        gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
        new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
        XStringFormats.Center);
        string filename = string.Empty;
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "PDF documents (.pdf)|*.pdf"; // Filter files by extension 

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Save document 
            filename = dlg.FileName;
        }
        document.Save(filename);
```

[SaveFileDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The generated report is a pdf so I need to save it as a pdf. Tried this already and didn't get the desired result.

Comment: I have modified my code for PDF saving based on PDFSharp

Comment: Worked Thanks for you help...!!! I have modified that portion(pdf document) so no problem and everything worked fine. I made a mistake that i have used File.WriteAllText() wrongly instead of just saving the document. Thanks for correcting me...Thanks again...!!!